# i need help on the Numpy Arrays

Tags: python

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
print(array[0:1][0:3])
```

its giving

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

it must give

[[1,2,3]]

Why is this happening

Comment: First part needs to be indexing and not slicing: `print(array[0][0:3])`

Comment: @omsel try print(array[0:2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use 2D array that's why if you try

- print(array[0:1][0:3])
  then output is in 2D array according to 0 index
- **[[1 2 3 4 5]]**

If try this

- print(array[0][0:3])
  then output is in a 1D array
- **[1 2 3]**

if you want 2D output then slicing set as

- print(array[0:1, 0:3])
  and output is in 2D array
- **[[1 2 3]]**

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
print(array[0:1,0:3])
```

result:

```
[[1 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why is this happening*

You are doing on 2D array `[0:1]` which might be read as *do 2D array consisting of 1 top rows*, then you do `[0:3]` at result - which is 2D array - and thus might be read as *do 2D array consisting of 3 top rows*, as there is already 1 row only you do end with 2D array having single row.
If this is consufing I hope following example with simple `list` will help:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = x[0:3][0:5]
print(y)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
print(array[:1][0][:3])
```